# how to rename column name with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need help with SQL Server Table Column.
I´m trying to rename Column Name, but this doesn't work.

```
USE COST_mesta_test
GO
EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[1965$].obec' , 'people' , 'COLUMN'
GO
```

I tried different combination of brackets [] and path to table "obec"
(for example: 1965.obec; 1965$.obec; 1965.[obec]; etc.)
But still i get an error:

> Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype
>   (COLUMN) is wrong.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I don't really understand how your table is set up - ie. the table name, the column name etc - so this is an example of how the proc works for column renames:

If I had a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company](
[ID] [int],
[CompanyName] [varchar](20)
)
```

and wanted to change the `[CompanyName]` column, this is the command:

```
EXEC sys.sp_rename 
    @objname = N'dbo.Company.CompanyName', 
    @newname = 'Name', 
    @objtype = 'COLUMN'
```

I suspect that your first argument is not correct.

From the documentation ([sp_rename (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx))

> If the object to be renamed is a column in a table, object_name must be in the form **table.column** or **schema.table.column**. If the object to be renamed is an index, object_name must be in the form table.index or schema.table.index

Comment: Note: this is said implicitly in answer, but to affirm it explicitly (since original question seems like it was getting error because of it), the brackets in the object name should be removed for the sp_rename call.  e.g., instead of '[dbo].[1965$].obec', it would be 'dbo.1965$.obec' for the purposes of this procedure (and other MS internals that use an object name string like that).

Answer (score 4):

You can also change the column name by right-clicking on the Column name and choosing 'rename' option in the Object Explorer.

Comment: Usually not a good idea, if you want to create migration scripts (which you often do).

Comment: Question is about rename with T-SQL not object explorer! It's not an answer.

Comment: @kami this is question title: "how to rename column name with T-SQL" Isn't it?

Comment: For tables with large amounts of data this can take quite a while to run since in the background it puts the data into a temp table then copies the data back over.